# How to remove a view and then create a new view behind the current view?

Tags: android

I have 3 views that I stack on top of each other by using a for loop at startup:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) m_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View m_view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        //load things into view
    }
```

The last loaded view (3rd view) is the one I see on the phone screen. If the user does an action the 3rd view is removed by using:

```
parentView.removeView(m_view);
```

Now I see the 2nd view. How do I add a view behind the 1st view so that I have always 3 views on the screen? I know that the last loaded view is always the one that the user will see.

Comment: Either you have to use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout as parentView.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Forgot to add my parentView is a RelativeLayout

Comment: He is right, either use a FrameLayout, put all three layouts inside, make one visible, and other two invisible. Or if you are dealing with complex layouts, use fragments.

Comment: @Darpan Is there someway I can reorder layouts?

Comment: Reorder as in? What I understand is if you close layout3, layout2 should be visible. And on closing layout2, 1 should be visible. So if you keep only one visible at a time, you could choose the one you want to show, ordering will not matter. Tell me if I am interpreting ordering wrong.

Comment: @Darpan Ah I understand what you mean now. In that case, at startup I can just load 2 views and then toggle the new views as visible or invisible. Is it better to use a regular LinearLayout as the view or change to FrameLayouts?

Comment: For your all three layouts, use a Relative layout as their parent. That's it. What layout you choose for three child layouts is your choice.